# Wordpress Divi Migrate issue

Tags: wordpress

I moved my wordless website to another hosting but the CSS and images are not showing.But if I use the visual builder the site seems fine and also in the preview looks fine. I can't understand where is the problem even if i click the save at the visual builder (divi) the site is still broken at the front end

Comment: How interesting. So what is your question?

Comment: the site only looks fine at preview and visual builder mode

Comment: What's the coding question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should include details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen on several migrations. The best solution I have found is to use All In One WP Migration. It's a super simple tool and it makes migration wicked easy.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

The other solution, which can be a pain, is to manually copy and paste your CSS and JS from the development environment to the live site.

Answer (score 2):

When migrating Divi, sometimes the CSS / and Customizer settings do not follow.. you'll have to Export from old site, and import to new one, this is available in the Customizer panel.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having links to the old website/server in your database. Use the inspector of your browser (right click -> inspect) and inspect the image which is not loading. Then have a look at the url of the image. It might still have the old url. You can either use a migration plugin or use a search and replace in your database to update the urls/paths to match the new server.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the plugin  https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

@Web_Limitless

Answer (score -1):

Actually when you transfer website to other hosting, in divi page builder it gets the image url of old website, so you have to update the images url again on new hosting and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

I will give you options:

**First option:** Use All In One WP Migration
**Second option:** In the divi module that has image just re-upload or re-choose the image so that it will match the image directory to the new one. In this case you have to do it manually.